Bluetooth devices not connecting automatically on startup
New Linux user here - for some reason I can't make my bluetooth headset and bluetooth mouse connect automatically on startup. They're both trusted devices and paired with the PC, but won't connect unless I tell them to.
Searching online I saw people solving the problem by using blueman so I installed it as well, but the auto-connect option on it is greyed out. I also looked around the main.conf file in /etc/bluetooth and AutoEnable is set to true.
Has anyone encountered this issue? Any idea how to solve it?

the first,Ensure that you have the necessary Bluetooth packages installed. Since you have already installed blueman, ensure you also have bluez and pulseaudio-module-bluetooth installed:
sudo apt-get install bluez pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
Make sure the Bluetooth services are enabled and running. You can check the status and enable them if needed:
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth
sudo systemctl start bluetooth
the last you can make script too to make automation running if is not working

How is this an answer? It works just does not auto connect so none of this is needed.
